# Acceptable field type and size for email address?

Tags: mysql, size, email-address, fieldtype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Common mySQL fields and their appropriate data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354763/common-mysql-fields-and-their-appropriate-data-types)
>   [What are the recommended database column sizes for names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512614/what-are-the-recommended-database-column-sizes-for-names)

I am looking for what would be the most correct field type and size to store email address into a mysql table.

I was initially considering varchar 255 but I think 255 might be too much or even too little what is the average size where I would be able to catch all kinda of valid email address ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the recommended database column sizes for names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512614/what-are-the-recommended-database-column-sizes-for-names) or [What are the recommended database column sizes for names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958/list-of-standard-lengths-for-database-fields) or [Common mySQL fields and their appropriate data types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354763/common-mysql-fields-and-their-appropriate-data-types)

Comment: @gbn, those first two have _nothing_ to do with email addresses but you're on a winner with the third. It appears this is a dupe.

Comment: @paxdiablo: accepted answer for 1st link mentions emails at 320 length, despite misleading title, which is what I saw. 2nd link title is wrong should be "List of standard lengths for database fields". All 3 were top 3 on Google search :-)

Comment: gbn well I did try searching around before making my question but using the terms mysql email was not sufficient to find anything related.

Comment: @gbn, I tend to only mark questions as a dupe when they're a dupe of the _question_ rather than the fact one of the answers may have the needed information. That's because my usual use case is to look for questions asking what I need to know. But that's just my opinion, and moot anyway, since your third link _was_ a dupe :-)

Comment: But isn't this more straight-forward than counting bytes as the depend on the encoding? Usually a programmer who designs his database will limit his columns to save space and will limit it depending on the expected input (e.g. his software design allows usernames up to 20 chars, so a varchar(20) will be sufficent, no matter which encoding)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

According to [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), forward and reverse path can be up to 256 chars long, so the email address can be up to 254 characters long. You're safe with using 255 chars.

Comment: Upvoted because you were first to talk about RFC 5321.

Comment: I love this answer. upvote.

Comment: Note that VARCHAR(255) doesn't necessarily mean 255 octets (as specified in the RFC). In fact http://stackoverflow.com/a/3739871/582917 says that CHAR, VARCHAR and TEXT types now counts logical character units, and if you're using utf8mb4 that could be variable size.

Comment: So I'm guessing the 255 limit should really be an octet limit and this needs to be considered when using utf8 encoded email addresses.

Comment: How to do you type "@" with out extranous ?

Answer (score 18):

[RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) and [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322), the relevant standards for SMTP, specify that an address consists of a local part and a domain. They further state that the maximum sizes for those are respectively 64 and 253 octets, though there's a further 256-octet limit imposed by the forward and reverse paths, including the punctuation (so 254 in reality).

So that should be all that you need for that.

Answer (score 15):

standard in any enterprise web application is varchar with 255 length

```
  varchar(255)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using VARCHAR 255 is probably the best idea here - there is nothing lost in giving few more bytes for each email address. 255 is also large enough to avoid cutting any sane email address.

Comment: You call 255 a sane email address? In the real world any email longer than 100 is likely to be automatically generated and used for nefarious purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Well varchar (255) is a standard for me. And i think it is good approach to store emails.

Answer (score 1):

[What is the maximum length of a valid email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-id)

you should use varchar field,
which make the size does not matter (assuming you are not building an index on it)